# How to show a 404 error page when a component is already loaded in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

First, I think I should point out that I know how to show a 404 error component/page when the Blazor router is unable to find a matching route. I know you could use a component within the `<NotFound>` tag in your App.razor. What I want to know rather is:

Say you a have page (a component with a route) called "Product.razor", and it receives a parameter from the route, the route is "/product/{productId}".

You send a request to the server to see if a product with that ID exists or not. If it doesn't, how could you throw a 404 error so that your 404 error page is shown?

In other words, how do you throw a 404 error when a matching route IS found and you are already in a component?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
@page "/product/{productId}"

@if (productExists)
{
    // Blah blah...
    if (product == null) // This means it's not loaded yet, so we show a loading indicator
    {
        <Loading />
    }
    else
    {
        <ProductCard Data="product" />
    }
}
else
{
    <NotFound />
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    Product product;

    bool productExists = true; // We start with the assumption that a product with the specified ID exists.

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Fetching data for the product:
        product = await someClient.GetProductAsync(productId);

        productExists = product != null;

        if (productExists)
        {
            // Fetching other data:
            // blah blah blah...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach fine? Isn't there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: This is the way to do it, May be you can create a generic component or a base page to encapsulate this behavior if you want to factorize it. but IMO it's fine like that

Comment: First you have to return httpStatus in your GetProductAsync . To to do that you can wrap it with another object that have Status property.

Second you check the status result then if its (4xx) you Navigate user your 404 page

Comment: @nAviD I'm aware of those steps, my question was how to navigate the user to the 404 page exactly.

Comment: @Arad Manually. by using @ inject NavigationManager navigationManager and then navigationManager.NavigateTo("Your url or rout") .

Comment: @nAviD Correct, but that would redirect the page, which means it causes the URL to change, I don't really want that. I just wanted to merely "show" my normal 404 page which is usually present within the <NotFound> tag in your App.razor. And I found out that what I already did is apparently the only way to do it at the moment.

Comment: @Arad then you should alter productExists  to property instead of field. Also change courseExists to productExists .

Comment: @nAviD `courseExists` was just a mistake I made when I was copying and pasting the code from my project, sorry about that. So, yes, I had already done that and it works, thanks. However, I don't see why you say that it should be a property instead of a field?!

Comment: @Arad becuase if you use field you have to call StateHasChanged() method manually. Even when you use property in many cases again you have to call StateHasChanged()

Comment: @Arad what have you eventually settled on?

Comment: @Bokue I actually no longer use Blazor. You're going to have to do some research into what the standard approach to doing this in Blazor currently is.